# Find value for equation to be contained in interval

Tags: real-analysis, recurrence-relations

I've been thinking if you can always find $x$ such

$$x-\frac{x-\epsilon\sin(x)-M}{1-\epsilon\cos(x)} \in [0, \pi]$$

with $\epsilon \in [0, 1]$ fixed, $M \in ]0, \pi[$. I've tried finding a bound for the equation but I can't find anything useful. This problem rises as a modification where $\epsilon$ is free and $x$ is fixed.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly - the expression as a function of x is continuous on R because the denominator is never zero (for epsilon<1). You can easily find some x such that the expression attains a value greater than pi or less than 0. Then by continuity, the function attains a value in the interval

Comment: Does $M\in ]0,\pi[$ mean $M\le 0$ or $M\ge \pi$?

Comment: @Tavish It means $0\leq M \leq \pi$

Comment: Why the outward brackets then?

Comment: @Tavish is the notation for open interval that we follow in our university

Comment: I see. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x=\pi$, $$\pi-\frac{\pi-M}{1+\epsilon}\in[0,\pi] \\ \iff \frac{\pi-M}{1+\epsilon} \in [0,\pi] $$ But this is true as $$\frac{\pi-M}{1+\epsilon} \le \frac{\pi-0}{1+0} = \pi $$ and $$\ge \frac{\pi-\pi}{1+1} = 0$$